# Laravel Schedule command does not work

Tags: windows, laravel, command-line, cron, scheduled-tasks

I used laravel 5 in my project. I wanted to create a scheduler for inserting user. In kernel.php, I put my codes and set the scheduler.

[image]

I created a command class named "InsertUser" and put it in kernel.php $commands variable.

[image]

In command line, I ran "php artisan schedule:run". But I found "No scheduled commands are ready to run.". If  I used call function instead of command function (in lernel.php), it was working fine. Please help me.

Comment: You define executing your task exactly in 18:16, are you sure your time exactly this?

Comment: When I run "php artisan schedule:run" in CLI, it was 18:16 (6:16 PM) at my machine.

Comment: If it will be 1 second more, the job wouldn't be executed. So, you can try to define executing the job in every minute. And try to catch the time :)

Comment: please be sure your machine is where php is running... and not on virtual machine... best option is to var_dump the datetime to check

Comment: I setup a schedule task in my machine (windows) that is started at say 10:00 AM. This task will repeat every 1 minute. In laravel kernel.php, $schedule->command('insert:user')
  ->everyFiveMinutes(); but it is not working

Answer (score 4):

The **Laravel Scheduler** needs a cron job that runs the `php artisan schedule:run` command periodically, which in turn evaluates any scheduled commands and runs them accordingly.

From your screenshot I see you're running Windows, which means you can't use the job code snippet from the [Starting The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling#introduction) section in the documentation because there is no `cron` on Windows. Windows is not officially supported for the task scheduler because of that and no instructions for it can be found in the documentation.

---

You could however get around the problem by creating a batch file, say `scheduler.bat`, that has the following contents:

```
cd c:\lamp\www\larasoft
php artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1
```

Then you can add a Windows [Scheduler Task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) to run that file every minute.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. But no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Windows does support **Laravel Scheduler** but, you've to run the command on your own for multiple times. Since we can't use **Windows Task Scheduler** to run for every 1 min as we can do with linux crontab. If you're using windows for development environment and want to test if command is working on not you can try this

If you run the

> php artisan schedule:run

command for multiple times by giving a min gap for each trial it'll work.

[image]

If you want to run directly the command you can follow this.

> "path\to\php.exe" "artisan" YourCommand > "NUL" 2>&1 &

**In your case**

1. > Run "where php.exe" in command prompt
2. > Copy The php location
3. > "paste\your\php\location" "artisan" InsertUser > "NUL" 2>&1 &